# How to connect typeorm to local sql server without error about self certificate (previous answers fail)?

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

On a windows machine with SQL Server 15 installed locally here is my ormconfig.ts

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  "type": "mssql",
  "entities": [
    "dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}",
  ],
  "migrationsTableName": "migrations_history",
  "migrations": [
    "dist/src/migrations/*{.ts,.js}",
  ],
  "synchronize": false,
  "logging": true,
  "database": "MyDb",
  "port": 1433,
  "host": "localhost",
  "username": "MyUserName",
  "password": "MyPassword",
  
  "options": {
    "encrypt": true,
    "trustServerCertificate": true,
  }

});
```

TCP/IP is enabled as well as connecting with SQL authentication.
I tried to connect directly with 'tedious' and 'mssql' with the exact same config and it worked.

But when my nestJS app tries to connect with typeorm it gets the error:

> Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate

typeorm version is 0.3.17, mssql is 9.3.2 and SQL Server is v15.
Note that my app can connect fine to a remove Azure Sql Server.
Also, I tried with `"encrypt": false` but same error.

Comment: Have you tried updating from typeorm 0.3.6 yet? `option.trustServerCertificate` only got added in typeorm 0.3.16. References: [fix: add trustServerCertificate option to SqlServerConnectionOptions #9985](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9985) and [Changelog - 0.3.16 (2023-05-09)](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/#0.3.16-2023-05-09)

Comment: I upgraded to 0.3.17 (and edited the question accordingly): same error :-(